# Ruby on Rails Questions For A newcomer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have recently started to code. I knew basic Javascript, HTML, and CSS from a high school class. I am self-teaching myself and I have a few questions I have, that someone more experienced can help me with.

1. Should I continue to code on my computer (Windows 10, 64 bit, 16 RAM) or try something else? I was able to get access to RubyMine as a student license but I still can not figure out how to use it. I have installed most the pre - requisites such as Ruby, Rails, GIT, Heroku, and all. Courses I am taking pursue me to use online IDE's such as nitrous or cloud9. So what should I do, is using an online IDE better, or just continue coding on Windows.
2. Should I halt my ruby on rails learning and learn JavaScript first? I have a good understanding of HTML and CSS. I did not really learn JavaScript. Should I know JavaScript before continuing.
3. Can Ruby on Rails help me build mobile apps? I did a couple of Google searches over this and found a few websites but no definitive answer. After learning Ruby on Rails will I still need to use Java for a mobile app, or could I use Ruby to make a mobile app just like a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've jumped around quite a bit, and did some ruby on rails. I know someone who took an 'intensive training course' on Ruby on Rails, and swears by it. It wasn't for me. There are so many competing technologies, it's hard to tell what will do the best in the future.

1. Should I continue to code on my computer? Yes, you absolutely should. Why wouldn't you want to do both? Partition your hard drive and have a dual boot! (maybe not if you have a laptop) Linux keeps you a bit closer to the terminal, but using a windows machine gives you access to powerful IDE's.
2. If you want to be a serious full-stack developer that hits mobile apps. Shift more towards Javascript/Angular/Node etc. Javascript is a very robust language these days, if you know a bit about it, you can work in all tiers of development(arguably)
3. Yes you can, with RubyMotion. I haven't heard much about it, and it has been around for some time. So it seems like other technologies are blowing it out of the water.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From my humble point of view:

1 - The truth is, you will avoid a serious amount of headaches with gems and dependencies if you stick with Linux or mac, if you never used before, believe me, it is worth it to get used to it and learn, you'll be more productive. Also, why not keeping it simple? the command line is your friend, with that and your favorite text editor, you can do anything, even [debugging](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) .

2 - I don't think there's like a 100% accurate guideline on this, I think you should do what feels more natural to you, it is important to know the basics on JavaScript, but that won't keep you from learning ruby, or rails.

3 - To be honest, never thought of it, but apparently [yes](http://www.rubymotion.com/). Sorry, can't elaborate more on this one.

In conclusion: be patient, be persistent, surely it is a lot to absorb, but slowly things will fit together.

Comment: Thanks for the help.